# Showing a hidden link upon clicking another link

Tags: jquery

I have a page that will show 2 graphs, with different information in them, depending on which link is clicked at the top of my page (adding the variable in the address line).

When clicking this link, i also want to have a button appear below the graphs, adding an option to download the entire database.

I have looked into this, and found a solution that "should" work, but it does not.

My Menu:

```
 <div class="menu">
    <a href="mf.html?area=AC">KMA</a>
    <a href="mf.html?area=OC">KMO</a>
 </div>
```

The jQuery (placed inside the Docuemnt.ready function):

```
$("#menu").click(function () {
    $("#downloadlink").show();
});
```

And lastly, the link i want make appear: 
        
        Click here to download databse

The above does not work. If anyone could provide help on the matter, i would be much appreciated, as im quite frankly getting a bit frustrated, this close to the weekend!

Thanks in advance, Jon.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$(".menu a").click(function () {
    $("#downloadlink").show();
});
```

Comment: Thank you alot of trying, but sadly, this did not solve the problem.

Comment: Right. Use class instead of id selector. I updated my answer appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

it´s difficult to figure out what´s the problem but you could try to trigger the click on the anchors, it may be they are in "front" of the div so you click them instead of div.menu

```
$(".menu a").click(function () {
    $("#downloadlink").show();
});
```

Comment: I attempted this, but it doesn't work either, although im sure you guys are closer to the correct solution than i was. 

Could the problem be caused by the fact that i place style="display:none;" in the div of the downloadlink, causing it to "rehide" the link when the page is "reloaded"?

Comment: if youre talking about showing the downloadlink on another page, the .show() in your initial page has no effect on another page,, why dont you  just set $(document).ready(function(){$('#downloadlink').show();}); in your  "mf.html?area=AC"

Answer (score 1):

The class selector is of the form `.classname` and not `#classname`

```
$('.menu a').click(function() {
    $("#downloadlink").show();
    return false; // important
});
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Hmm, return false; causes neither the graphs nor the link to show up.

Comment: I mean the link didn't show up anyway, but now neither does the graphs.

Comment: If you dont `return false` the link won't show up. If you do the graphs wont. Can't have both since showing the graphs require the user to navigate away from the current page.

Comment: Also, check the selector usage `#downloadlink` is correct. If the hidden link's class name is `downloadlink`, the selector should be `.downloadlink` and not `#downloadlink`